# Access specific index of array returned from web scrape using puppeteer

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

Here is my script - it scrapes amazon to check for product availability using puppeteer

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');


//URL
scrape('https://www.amazon.co.uk/PlayStation-9395003-5-Console/dp/B08H95Y452/ref=sr_1_1?dchild=1&keywords=ps5&qid=1613570801&sr=8-1');

/**
 *
 * Scrape PS5
 *
 */
async function scrape(url)
{

    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto(url);

        //get availability
        const [el2] = await page.$x('//*[@id="availability"]/span');
        const txt1 = el2.getProperty('textContent');
        const rawTxt1 = (await txt1)._remoteObject.value;

        //log data
        console.log({rawTxt1});

        //close browser
        browser.close();

}
```

It returns this to the console after i log it

[image]

i want it to return only 'currently unavailable'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
async function scrape(url)
{

    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto(url);
    await page.waitForSelector("div#availability")
    const  result = await page.evaluate(()=>{
        return Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("div#availability span.a-size-medium")).map((el)=> el.innerText)
    });
    //log data
    console.log(result)

        //close browser
        browser.close();

}
```

Output:

```
["Currently unavailable."]
```